# Error generating components with Angular CLI: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created a project with angular-cli and created some components using the `ng g component <componentname>` command. After doing some administration and preparing the code for further development, and suddenly I get `Error: Cannot read property '0' of null` when running the same command. `ng g service services/<servicename>` works without any issues.

my .angular-cli.json is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "dd-frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I generated a new app with `ng new testApp` and copied the add.module.ts into the failing project. Then I reran the failing command, and it worked.

here is the failing app.module.ts:

```
//core imports
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

//components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

//Services 
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
//import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
AboutComponent,
LoginComponent,
DashboardComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
FlashMessagesModule
],
providers: [
AuthService/*,
AuthGuard*/
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: was your app originally created using angular-cli?

Comment: Yes. `ng new projectname`

Answer (score 0):

Much dependent on what 'administration' tasks you did. Did you move the app altogether or moved files or sub-folders within the app? See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4736#issuecomment-297266158) answer (and also other recommendations there if that doesn't help). Hope it helps.

Comment: I added some style sheets and scripts (bootstrap, dependencies ), set origin for git for upload to bitbucket, added some stuff in a couple of .ts files on other components

Comment: I see. Did you take a look at the link, see if that rings any bell? Are you on windows?

Comment: I didn't move the project. I tried another project created in the same manner, and tried moving it since, but with no altered experience. i also compared the angular-cli.json with the working project....

Comment: What platform are you working on? Also, try using `ng init` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4736#issuecomment-284900233). Trying to see if any of these work for you

Comment: i actally found the `ng init` by myself, and that gives me `The specified command init is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.`