# Problems creating a component with angular/cli

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a component with angular/cli with  this command and I recive this error:

```
ng generate component cursos
Cannot read property '0' of null
```

I have tried to uninstall angular/cli, angular and as well I have follow this other thread [Error generating components with Angular CLI: Cannot read property '0' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433112/error-generating-components-with-angular-cli-cannot-read-property-0-of-null)
 and nothing. If I write a ng --version I have this:

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 10.9.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.5
@angular/cli                      6.1.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               0.7.5
@schematics/update                0.7.5
rxjs                              6.3.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Could you please, help me to guess why I have this error?. Thanks so much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433112/error-generating-components-with-angular-cli-cannot-read-property-0-of-null see this problem

Comment: This is the same link I have posted on the explanation. However, this is angular 6.1.5 so there is no .angular-cli because now is called angular.json...thanks